# jquery event handler on mobile devices- imitate drawing action

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, event-handling

i got a grid that contains a picture (see fiddle below), what i want to do is imitate a drawing action.

i made to work on my personal computer, but for some reasen it dosen't wort on mobile. i gues that there are different handling event for mobilr devices.

as you can see now i use `mouseenter` event.
the question is how do i make it work on mobile?

this is my code:
js

```
    createLoop();


$('.b').bind('mouseenter', StartDragSelect);




function createLoop() {
    var length = 30;
    var text = "";
    var demo = $("#demo")
    for ( i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var rowElement = $('<div class="a"></div>');
        demo.append(rowElement);
        for (var x = 0; x < length; x++) {
            createGridItem(rowElement, i, x);
        }
    }
}

function createGridItem(rootElement, i, x) {
    var pix = 10;
    var currItem = $('<div class="b" id="a' + i + x + '" style="top:' + i * pix + 'px; left: ' + x * pix + 'px;  background-position-x: -' + x * pix + 'px ; background-position-y:-' + i * pix + 'px";"></div>');
    $(rootElement).append(currItem);
}




var gridSize = length * length;
var letter = getParameterByName("letter");

function StartDragSelect(obj) {
    obj = obj.currentTarget;
    if (obj.className == "selected") {
        obj.className = "b";

    } else {
        obj.className = "selected";

    }

    $(obj).css({
        "background-image" : "url('http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/7.jpg')"
    });
}
```

this is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/davseveloff/fov05vgk/2/)

any help would be great!
tnx

Answer (score 1):

There is no such an event `mouseenter`on mobile devices. You have to operate with `touchstart` `touchmove` and `touchend` to imitate somehow the mouseenter event on mobile devices.

Here are the touch events on mobile devices:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events

For a real use case you might check the source for this pen i did: http://codepen.io/esimov/pen/Kefql/